Snowflake Hybrid Tables - High Query Compilation Time
We're evaluating Snowflake Hybrid Tables for transactional use cases but see high query compilation times (high for transactional purposes).
In our tests with Hybrid Tables containing just a few records, the query compilation time is 100ms to 180ms for trivial operations like simple SELECT or INSERT queries.
While the execution time is around 30ms.
This behavior appears to be independent of the warehouse size.
Are there ways to reduce the query compilation time to tens of milliseconds?
Or is this compilation time (100ms+) a limitation of hybrid tables?
Example (updated):
CREATE HYBRID TABLE TEST (
    ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
    VALUE VARCHAR(255),
    primary key (ID)
);

Insert duration 117ms: (Compilation: 91ms, Execution: 26ms)
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, 'value');

Select duration 1.7s: (Compilation: 1.3s, Execution: 408ms)
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM TEST LIMIT 100

Select duration 208ms: (Compilation: 185ms, Execution: 23ms)
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM TEST WHERE ID = 1

Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please post enough information, query which is taking time for compilation is not posted.

Updated question with examples
